# rsync prints "skipping non-regular file" for what appears to be a regular directory

Tags: linux, unix, backup, rsync, directory

I back up my files using rsync. Right after a sync, I ran it expecting to see nothing, but instead it looked like it was skipping directories. I've (obviously) changed names, but I believe I've still captured all the information I could. What's happening here?

```
$ ls -l /source/backup/myfiles
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me  4096 2010-10-03 14:00 foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me  4096 2011-08-03 23:49 bar
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me  4096 2011-08-18 18:58 baz

$ ls -l /destination/backup/myfiles
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me  4096 2010-10-03 14:00 foo
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me  4096 2011-08-03 23:49 bar
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me  4096 2011-08-18 18:58 baz

$ file /source/backup/myfiles/foo
/source/backup/myfiles/foo/: directory
```

Then I sync (expecting no changes):

```
$ rsync -rtvp /source/backup /destination
sending incremental file list
backup/myfiles
skipping non-regular file "backup/myfiles/foo"
skipping non-regular file "backup/myfiles/bar"
```

And here's the weird part:

```
$ echo 'hi' > /source/backup/myfiles/foo/test
$ rsync -rtvp /source/backup /destination
sending incremental file list
backup/myfiles
backup/myfiles/foo
backup/myfiles/foo/test
skipping non-regular file "backup/myfiles/foo"
skipping non-regular file "backup/myfiles/bar"
```

So it worked:

```
$ ls -l /source/backup/myfiles/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  3126091 2010-06-15 22:22 IMGP1856.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  3473038 2010-06-15 22:30 P1010615.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me        3 2011-08-24 13:53 test

$ ls -l /destination/backup/myfiles/foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  3126091 2010-06-15 22:22 IMGP1856.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me  3473038 2010-06-15 22:30 P1010615.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me        3 2011-08-24 13:53 test
```

but still:

```
$ rsync -rtvp /source/backup /destination
sending incremental file list
backup/myfiles
skipping non-regular file "backup/myfiles/foo"
skipping non-regular file "backup/myfiles/bar"
```

Other notes:

My actual directories "foo" and "bar" do have spaces, but no other strange characters. Other directories have spaces and have no problem. I 'stat'-ed and saw no differences between the directories that don't rsync and the ones that do.

If you need more information, just ask.

Answer (score 66):

Are you absolutely sure those individual **files** are not symbolic links?

Rsync has a few useful flags such as `-l` which will "copy symlinks as symlinks". Adding `-l` to your command:

```
rsync -rtvpl /source/backup /destination
```

---

I believe symlinks are skipped by default because they can be a security risk. Check the man page or --help for more info on this:

```
rsync --help | grep link
```

---

To verify these are symbolic links or pro-actively to find symbolic links you can use **file** or **find**:

```
$ file /path/to/file
/path/to/file: symbolic link to `/path/file`
$ find /path -type l
/path/to/file
```

Comment: Yet another example of a poorly worded status/error message.     
If your code is skipping the file because it is a symlink, then why not print "skipping symlink"?

Comment: My guess is that rsync is older than symlinks. Maybe they just haven't bothered to add it since it is such a rare use-case. Nothing stopping you from contributing: https://rsync.samba.org/bugzilla.html

Answer (score 6):

Are you absolutely sure that it's not a symbolic link directory?

try a:

```
file /source/backup/myfiles/foo
```

to make sure it's a directory

Also, it could very well be a loopback mount
try

```
mount
```

and make sure that /source/backup/myfiles/foo is not listed.

Comment: `$ file /source/backup/myfiles/foo`
`/source/backup/myfiles/foo/: directory`

and 'mount' shows the filesystems that /source and /destination are on, but no 'lower' than that.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the below command, most probably it will work for you:

```
rsync -ravz /source/backup /destination
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, it will work

```
rsync -rtvp /source/backup /destination
```

Comment: Files are skipped anyway

Answer (score 0):

I personally always use this syntax in my script and works a treat to backup the entire system (skipping sys/* & proc/* nfs4/*)

```
sudo rsync --delete --stats  --exclude-from $EXCLUDE -rlptgoDv / $TARGET/ | tee -a $LOG
```

Here is my script run by root's cron daily:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
NFS="/nfs4"
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
EXCLUDE="/home/gcclinux/Backups/root-rsync.excludes"
TARGET="${NFS}/${HOSTNAME}/SYS"
LOGDIR="${NFS}/${HOSTNAME}/SYS-LOG"
CMD=`/usr/bin/stat -f -L -c %T ${NFS}`

## CHECK IF NFS IS MOUNTED...

if [[ ! $CMD == "nfs" ]];then
    echo "NFS NOT MOUNTED"
    exit 1
fi

## CHECK IF LOG DIRECTORY EXIST

if [ ! -d "$LOGDIR" ]; then
    /bin/mkdir -p $LOGDIR
fi

## CREATE LOG HEADER
LOG=$LOGDIR/"rsync_result."$TIMESTAMP".txt"

echo "-------------------------------------------------------" | tee -a $LOG
echo `date` | tee -a $LOG
echo "" | tee -a $LOG

## START RUNNING BACKUP
/usr/bin/rsync --delete --stats  --exclude-from $EXCLUDE -rlptgoDv / $TARGET/ | tee -a $LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases just copy file to another location (like home) then try again