# After rsync assets ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am trying to deploy a Ruby On Rails app to an aws instance. The original problem was that the deployment process was stuck at compiling assets.
And seems that this was a common scenario that other developers tend to workaround by removing the compile step, compile the assets locally and then rsync them to the remote server.
So I decided to give it a try following what is suggested here:
[Rails 5.1 capistrano is stuck at webpacker compiling assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555150/rails-5-1-capistrano-is-stuck-at-webpacker-compiling-assets)
After checking this question:
[pipeline assets precompile disable does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276934/pipeline-assets-precompile-disable-does-not-seem-to-work)
I found how to skip assets precompile by removing require 'capistrano/rails' from my Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.5'

require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
before 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:rsync_assets'

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Here deploy:rsync_assets is invoked before deploy:updated.
deploy:rsync_assets is supossed to:

- exec locally asstes:precompile
- rsync remote

For the rsync there was a problem with "skipping non-regular file"
because a lot of them are symlinks:
[rsync prints "skipping non-regular file" for what appears to be a regular directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180420/rsync-prints-skipping-non-regular-file-for-what-appears-to-be-a-regular-direct)
fixed adding -l to the command to copy the symlinks.
Now the problem is that: ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.)
There is an application.scss **but there never was an application.css file. The app works fine locally, and also in other servers(render and heroku). Even I accomplished to deploy it in aws once, always without an application.css** so I can figure out why is asking for it now?
Here is my deploy.rb:

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.17.2"


require 'capistrano-db-tasks'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:develaper/my_app.git'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/my_app'
set :branch, 'develop'
set :bundle_flags, "--deployment"

# set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] if ENV['BRANCH']

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/master.key}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/packs public/system}

set :keep_releases, 3
set :keep_assets, 3

set :db_local_clean, true
set :db_remote_clean, true

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'locally precompile and rsync'
  task :rsync_assets do
    host = "myhost.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    app_folder = "/home/deploy/my_app"
    puts Airbrussh::Colors.yellow('** Skipping asset compile.')
    rsync_host = host.to_s
    run_locally do
      execute "RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile"
      execute "rsync -l --recursive --times --rsh=ssh --compress --human-readable --progress --delete ./public/ deploy@#{rsync_host}:#{app_folder}/shared/public/"
      # execute "rm -rf public/assets"
      # execute "rm -rf tmp/cache/assets"
    end
  end

  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

The result of running rails webpacker:info

```
Ruby: ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
Rails: 6.1.0
Webpacker: 4.3.0
Node: v12.22.12
Yarn: 1.22.19

@rails/webpacker: 
ww_app@0.1.0 /home/my_user/Development/my_app
└── @rails/webpacker@4.2.2 

Is bin/webpack present?: true
Is bin/webpack-dev-server present?: true
Is bin/yarn present?: true
```

As suggested here:
[Rails: Webpacker 4.2 can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161189/rails-webpacker-4-2-cant-find-application-in-app-public-packs-manifest-json-h)

I changed my config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

and config/webpacker.yml

```
production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: true

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false
```